Enable DefaultAccountState to Frozen on existent mint account
how to initialize DefaultAccountState to Frozen on already created mint account with spl-token cli.

If the mint is already created, you cannot add new extensions. This behavior protects users from a malicious mint creator from adding new or unexpected functionality after token creation.
If you're creating a new mint, you can add the extension by running:
spl-token create-token --default-account-state frozen --enable-freeze --program-2022

